# Autohotkey Open Folder of Current Application or Process

Tags: autohotkey

In this code no open current application folder because the FilePath variable include exe file name

```
F11::
PID = 0
WinGet, hWnd,, A
DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "UInt", hWnd, "UInt *", PID)
hProcess := DllCall("OpenProcess",  "UInt", 0x400 | 0x10, "Int", False
                                 ,  "UInt", PID)
PathLength = 260*2
VarSetCapacity(FilePath, PathLength, 0)
DllCall("Psapi.dll\GetModuleFileNameExW", "UInt", hProcess, "Int", 0, "Str", FilePath, "UInt", PathLength)

DllCall("CloseHandle", "UInt", hProcess)

Run, Explorer %FilePath%
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
F11::
WinGet, path, ProcessPath, A
SplitPath, path, name, dir
Run, explorer.exe %dir%
return
```

or:

```
F11::
WinGet, path, ProcessPath, A
Run, % "explorer.exe /select," . path
return
```

Comment: @dcaro JFYI You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow). Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. While you can accept only one answer, you can upvote as many answer as you find useful, including the accepted one.

Comment: @user3419297 JFYI You also can vote for a question when you think the question is useful and is a good one to answer.